# How to create and add a new variable based on the sum of values of a group

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data set called test with multiple observations per participant. Every participant has a unique id, but several observations (1 row in the data = 1 observation). I have to reduce the data set to 1 row per participant and add two new variables which are a sum of the no. of observations per participant and the sum of points he or she received per observation.

I already got this values, but how can I create and add these two variables to my data set based on this code?

```
test %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  summarize(sum_communities = sum(id/id, na.rm = TRUE))
```

```
test %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  summarize(sum_points = sum(points, na.rm = TRUE))
```

Comment: I do not any assignment of values to a name. You still need to do so even in the tidyverse.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Answer (score 0):

I created a demo data in test table. test_reduced table has desired output.

```
library(dplyr)
test = data.frame("Participent" =c("A","A","A","B","B","C","C","C", "C"), 
       "Observation" = c(4,5,6,4,7,4,6,6,3))
test_reduced = test %>% group_by(Participent) %>% 
                summarise(count = n(), sum = sum(Observation))
```

Output:

```
 # A tibble: 3 x 3
  Participent count   sum
  <fct>       <int> <dbl>
 1 A               3    15
 2 B               2    11
 3 C               4    19
```